# Scheme Binary Search Tree Error (R5RS)

Tags: scheme, binary-search-tree, racket, r5rs

I am completely new to Scheme and functional languages in general.  I am trying to create a binary search tree.  The format of a node is a list of three elements, the first being the value at the node, the second being the left child node, and the third being the right child node.  I have a "make" function, which creates an empty tree: ( () () () ).  I also have the insert function.  Here is the code:

```
;Inserts a number into the tree
(define (insert t x)
  (cond ((null? (car t))
      (list x (make) (make)))
      ((< x (car t))
       ((list (car t) ((insert (cadr t)  x)) (caddr t))))
      ((> x (car t))
       ((list (car t) (cadr t) ((insert (caddr t) x)) )))

  )
)

;Makes a new empty tree
(define (make)
  (list (list) (list) (list))
)
```

To test it, I run the following lines:

```
> (define b1 (make))
> (define b2 (insert b1 1))
> b2
(1 (() () ()) (() () ()))
> (define b3 (insert b2 2))
```

I then receive the following error:

```
application: not a procedure;
expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
given: (2 (() () ()) (() () ()))
arguments...: [none]
```

I have checked and re-checked my parentheses...and running it in debug mode, I see it fails at the END of inserting 2 into the tree.  Until the, it works as planned.  Is this the cause of a foolish syntax/logic error on my part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
((list (car t) ((insert (cadr t)  x)) (caddr t)))
```

The outer pair of parentheses is the problem here. `(list (car t) ((insert (cadr t)  x)) (caddr t))` gives you a list. By wrapping another pair of parentheses around it, you're trying to apply that list as if it was a function, which you can't - thus the error message.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had a feeling it was a stupid mistake on my part. Worked like a charm.  I guess the whole "When in doubt, add more parentheses" doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Ryan You know how Python is indentation-sensitive, and Ruby is whitespace-sensitive? Lisp and Scheme are parentheses-sensitive.